# Master Pages in DotNetNuke

Tags: master-pages, dotnetnuke

I want to create a master page for my dotnetnuke web application, can u give me guide lines for how to create master page and how to register into dotnetnuke.

Answer (score 3):

DotNetNuke does not use Master Pages.  It uses a concept known as "skinning" to create consistent views of your website.

At a basic level, a skin is an .ascx control that has `<div runat="server">` in places where users can add modules.

It's not completely up-to-date, but the [Skinning Guide](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=UvGirRQpGRo%3d&tabid=478&mid=857) document on DotNetNuke.com is probably a good place to start.